# OWIN - Customizing UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin

I had to customize the `UserManager` class to find and authenticate users in the company structure (mixes Active Directory Authentication with another Oracle Authetication). Though I have implemented the `FindAsync` and `CreateIdentityAsync`, the user is not set as authenticated.

My `UserManager` implementation:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web;
using MyProject.Common;
using MyProject.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyProject.Infrastructure
{
    public class GNUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public GNUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store) : base(store)
        {

        }        

        public override async Task<ApplicationUser> FindAsync(string userName, string password)
        {
            /* Performs some logic here that returns true */

            if (foundUser) {
                return await Task.Run(() => new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = userName, 
                    Id = userName
                });
            }

            throw new Exception("User not found.");
        }

        public override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user, string authenticationType)
        {
            IList<Claim> claimCollection = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Country, "Brazil"),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.UserName)
            };

            var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claimCollection, "Company Portal");

            return await Task.Run(() => claimsIdentity);  
        }
    }
}
```

What is lacking to have my user authenticated?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing this line.

```
 var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claimCollection, "Company Portal");
```

To this

```
var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claimCollection, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

That should generate your cookie for you that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

The UserManager manages the user identity in the database as well as validating credentials. In short, it's a DB lookup tool. To get the user "logged into" your app, you need to issue some sort of token (like a cookie for browser apps, or a token for api apps). The most recent approach in ASP.NET is with the Cookie Authentication Middleware for browser apps. See here for more info on the cookie middleware:

http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/

Comment: I saw this site yesterday, but it's only a glance about what I'm looking for. That's exactly the cookie generation that interests me.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the SignIn method created by an ASP.NET MVC 5 default project we can see this code:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
    AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

What we can notice is that `AuthenticationManager` wich is one who takes care of autenthication sign in, after we get the identity also is needed to SignIn with the `AuthenticationManager`. So maybe your problem is not with `UserManager`.

The `AuthenticationManager` instance in the *Controller* class is retrieved by this code:

```
private IAuthenticationManager AuthenticationManager
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
    }
}
```

Comment: This line: `AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);` executes normally, but no cookie is generated. Debugging this code I dive into `public override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user, string authenticationType)`. What I need to find out is how to generate the cookie.

Comment: Maybe can you call the base Method wich one you are overriding?

Comment: I am on chat now... check there

Answer (score 1):

Oracle Data Provider for .NET currently does not support Asynchronous Query and Save.